# Can you show a window while ApplicationDidFinishLaunching is still running?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

everyone
I'm working on a project that has to read the info from a .plist-file every time it starts up, and I was wondering if you could show a window at the beginning of the program that shows the progress of the ApplicationDidFinishLaunching fuction? Because I noticed that whenever the program starts up, the first window doesn't show up until this function has finished running.

Comment: You probably should make your `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` return pretty much instantly and do all extensive loading and processing later. You should present a Window / View as fast as possible and make the actual starting of the app a task that the controller for that window / view performs.

Comment: @luk2302 What action do I need to use in my NSWindowController so that it will run when the window becomes active?

Comment: You can add a loading screen and fire a notification when the loading is complete to load the next scenes of your project. Get back if you need help with it! :)

Comment: @luk2302 I created an NSWindowDelegate for my loading window and put my loading part in there, but when I use orderOut on the loading window from within the windowDidBecomeKey() function, it won't go away. Any tips?